# Showing a non-modal form from a modal form closes the modal form

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I have a modal form i'm showing.
e.g.

```
var form = new MyModalForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Within MyModalForm, i have a button which launches another form. This one is non-modal.

```
var helperForm = new MyHelperForm();
helperForm.Show();
```

When I click the button, HelperForm appears, however MyModalForm dissapears. What's going on and how do I correct this? I want the modal form to remain, and the helper non-modal form to be accessible.

I tried setting the Owner property of the Helper Form to be the modal form, but then both forms are not showing.

Comment: I dont know about the *showForm* method but to display a modal form you use *showDialog*. Your **helperForm** is ok.

Comment: What does `showForm` do?  That's not a standard method of the Form class.

Comment: sorry, showForm() was meant to be just show().

Comment: you say you have a modal form but you show it like this: form.Show(); This means that form is not modal but non modal. So both your forms are none modal. You have to do form.ShowDialog() to make your modal form modal and helperform.Show(this); to show the non modal form over your modal form

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. MyModalForm is called with ShowDialog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both your forms are non modal.
Try this :

```
using (var form = new.MyModalForm())
{
     form.ShowDialog(); // make this form modal
}
```

Within MyModalForm, i have a button which launches another form. This one is non-modal.

```
var helperForm = new MyHelperForm();
helperForm.Show(this); // this should be an instance of MyModalForm
```

Comment: yes. had a typo in my original post that shows that MyModalForm was called with Show(), not ShowDialog().

helperForm.Show(this); was the key here. works good.

Answer (score 0):

```
 instead of helperForm.show() call helperForm.showDialog()
 the helper form will appear and your modelForm will remain on screen.
```

Comment: I dont know who gave you an up vote but *showDialog* displays a **modal** form!  *Within MyModalForm, i have a button which launches another form. This one is* **non-modal.**

Comment: yes, my goal for HelperForm is for it to be non-modal, if it's possible.